# Does a new Grub install modify cleanly the master boot record?

Tags: grub2

When you reinstall Grub through the installer, does it automatically edit whatever existing boot record is there so that there is nothing left dangling (code-wise)? Or, do you actually need to clean things up in some manner?

(This may apply to Debian as well as any other Debian-based Linux that uses Grub).

Thanks.